# Loop through Visual Studio resources

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a C# WPF app and I've added some images into a subfolder called assets. Is there any way I can loop through all the images that i've added to the folder using pack URIs or something similar?

Comment: You have asked 22 questions only 11 of them you have accepted an answer.

Comment: Thats what that means! I thought it meant percentage of people who accepted my questions or something of the sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method gets all the file names in a resource-folder:

```
public static string[] GetResourcesUnder(string folder)
{
    folder = folder.ToLower() + "/";

    var assembly       = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var resourcesName  = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    var stream         = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcesName);
    var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(stream);

    var resources =
        from p in resourceReader.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
        let theme = (string)p.Key
        where theme.StartsWith(folder)
        select theme.Substring(folder.Length);

    return resources.ToArray();
}
```

Just need to put the head back on when you use them:

```
var files = GetResourcesUnder("Images");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string uriPath = "pack://application:,,,/Images/" + file;
    //...
}
```

I did *not* write this method, it's from another question here on SO, i'll try to find it...

**Edit:** It's from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069276/enumerating-files-in-an-embedded-resource-directory).