# How to read a text file in project's root directory?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to read the first line of a text file that I added to the root directory of my project. Meaning, my solution explorer is showing the .txt file along side my .cs files in my project.

So, I tried to do:

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"myfile.txt");
string myText = tr.ReadLine();
```

But this doesn't work since it's referring to the Bin Folder and my file isn't in there... How can I make this work? :/

Thanks

Comment: btw, StreamReader name is a bit confusing, Microsoft should have named that TextStreamReader in my opinion

Answer (score 167, accepted):

From Solution Explorer, right click on myfile.txt and choose "Properties"

From there, set the `Build Action` to `content`
and `Copy to Output Directory` to either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`

[image]

Comment: I'd rather not have this file exposed to my users... is there a way to embed it in the dll and read it from there?

Comment: @foreyez Add the string to your project as a resource, instead of using a file, perhaps. Note the data will not be unobtainable - How sensitive is the data this file contains?

Comment: Set the build option to `Embedded Resource` and read t the article  on how to read emebedded resource http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikola/archive/2008/05/14/embedded-resources.aspx

Comment: if i an creating setup for a project then i am not able to work with property. is there any other solution for that?

Answer (score 37):

You can use the following to get the root directory of a website project:

```
String FilePath;
FilePath = Server.MapPath("/MyWebSite");
```

Or you can get the base directory like so:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 33):

Add a Resource File to your project (Right Click Project->Properties->Resources). Where it says "strings", you can switch to be "files". Choose "Add Resource" and select your file.

You can now reference your file through the `Properties.Resources` collection.

Comment: When I tried this, I get "Illegal characters in path". The Resources seems to save your file contents as a string, and truncates it after a certain length.

Answer (score 19):

```
private string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

The method above will bring you something like this:

```
"C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myProjectNamespace\bin\Debug"
```

From here you can navigate backwards using System.IO.Directory.GetParent:

```
_filePath = Directory.GetParent(_filePath).FullName;
```

1 time will get you to \bin, 2 times will get you to \myProjectNamespace, so it would be like this:

```
_filePath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(_filePath).FullName).FullName;
```

Well, now you have something like "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myProjectNamespace", so just attach the final path to your fileName, for example:

```
_filePath += @"\myfile.txt";
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(_filePath);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but can
 _filePath = Path.Combine(_filePath, "myfile.txt"); // stylishly :)

Answer (score 15):

You can have it embedded (build action set to `Resource`) as well, this is how to retrieve it from there:

```
private static UnmanagedMemoryStream GetResourceStream(string resName)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var strResources = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
    var rStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strResources);
    var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(rStream);
    var items = resourceReader.OfType<DictionaryEntry>();
    var stream = items.First(x => (x.Key as string) == resName.ToLower()).Value;
    return (UnmanagedMemoryStream)stream;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string resName = "Test.txt";
    var file = GetResourceStream(resName);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        MessageBox.Show(line);
    }
}
```

*(Some code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069276/enumerating-files-in-an-embedded-resource-directory/5185454#5185454) by [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24898/charles))*

Answer (score 4):

You have to use absolute path in this case. But if you set the `CopyToOutputDirectory = CopyAlways`, it will work as you are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

In this code you access to `root` directory project:

```
 string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

then:

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(_filePath + "/cities2.json"))
```