# Accessing a local text file in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, path, text-files, streamreader

I'm building an executable application from WPF in visual studio, and I have a local text file added to the project (StringList.txt) that I'm trying to read into a List object.  What would the path for that file be for a StreamReader such that the executable can access the file when I deploy it and run in on another computer?

So far I have:

```
   List<String> list = new List<String>();

   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("~/Desktop/Deploy/StringList.txt");

    String line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        fields.Add(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }

    sr.Close();
```

**Deploy is the publish folder location

Comment: I think that person was trying to save a file to the project folder or something, but I'm just trying to access the local file within my project.  Whatever that answer was didn't work.  Thanks though.

Comment: These are the settings I needed to change to get it to work: [Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416564/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-projects-root-directory

Answer (score 1):

The `~/Desktop/Deploy/StringList.txt` wont work for WPF..
Try this:

```
// Get the directory where your entry assembly is located (your application)
var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

// Add your sub directory and filename
var filename = assemblyPath + "\\Desktop\\Deploy\\StringList.txt";

// Use it on your StreamReader
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
```

This will open the file within a subdirectory of your program.

Comment: What is _path?  It's giving me a compiler error on that.

Comment: @EliteZalba copy/paste mistake... changed it

Comment: That doesn't work :(

Comment: I have to imagine that there would be a simple way to read text files that are stored inside your program.  Would you have any suggestions for anything else that I can do that would keep a simple text file like this WITH the program so that it can easily be edited and updated?

Comment: What do  you mean with 'inside your program' Did you marked it as resource?