# Loading ResourceDictionary dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a folder in my project, **Templates**, full of (compiled) XAML ResourceDictionaries.

In a UserControl, I want to load all the templates into the ResourceDictionary. I would use code like the following:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (var resourceUri in new GetResourceUrisFromTemplatesFolder())
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            new ResourceDictionary
                { Source = new Uri(resourceUri, UriKind.Relative) });
}
```

What I need to write is the `GetResourceUrisFromTemplatesFolder` method. I need it to discover all the resources from that folder.

The URIs could take a form like `/MyAssembly;component/MyNS/Templates/Template12345.xaml` or `../../Templates/Template12345.xaml`

Is this possible?

Do I have to manually convert the names from the assembly's compiled resources (`MyAssembly.g.resources`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to manually convert the names from the assembly's compiled resources (MyAssembly.g.resources)?

That might be the case and i myself would approach it that way, however the question about how to do just that [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5069276/546730) already so it should be not that much of an issue. Make sure that the dictionaries' compile action matches, and you probably want to prefix the names with a pack uri.

Comment: Yup, it turned out to be quite easy

Answer (score 8):

BTW, one can also manually load a ResourceDictionary as it seems:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary(); 
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(dict, 
  new System.Uri("/SomeAssembly;component/SomeResourceDictionary.xaml",
  System.UriKind.Relative));
```

After that, can talk to that dict object using foreach on the Keys property it has etc

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596995(v=vs.95).aspx says

> The XAML file that is loaded can be either an application definition file (App.xaml, for example) >or a page file (MainPage.xaml, for example). The XAML file can be in one of the following locations:
>
> - Included in the application package.
> - Embedded in the application assembly.
> - Embedded within a library assembly at the site of origin.

Comment: That doesn't seem different from loading the dictionary with a `Source`. The "complex" part was not loading the dictionary, but generating the Uris.